# Appending a CSV file to end of another using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV files with the same column structure; A.csv and B.csv

I'm looking for a PowerShell way to append B.csv to the end of A.csv, without the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the answer with `Import-Csv | Export-Csv` for simplicity. Just be aware that it's probably not very efficient to parse both (potentially large) files as CSV when that's not really necessary.

This example doesn't make any assumptions about the structure of the files and just takes file 2 (without the first line) and appends it to file 1:

```
Get-Content .\file2.txt | where ReadCount -gt 1 >> .\file1.txt
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from more explanation regarding the `where ReadCount -gt 1` part of the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can just try:

```
Import-Csv a.csv, b.csv | Export-Csv c.csv -notype
```

Comment: Will this remove the header from b.csv before adding it to a.csv?

Comment: Yes it will, The explanation is that `Import-Csv` read the lines for both files `a.csv` and `b.csv` and transform each line in an object, then it writes all the objects to `c.csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [@JPBlanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42317914/appending-a-csv-file-to-end-of-another-using-powershell/42318435#42318435):

```
 $files=@("C:\temp\test\a.csv", "C:\temp20170219\test\b.csv")
 import-csv $files | export-csv -NoType "c:\temp\c.csv"
```